# My first linux driver, its for a gpio button, a little confused on interrupts

Tags: linux-device-driver

So this is a power button, I need it to turn the power off or go to sleep depending on how long you hold it. That's the simple part. I've never written a driver from scratch, but have tweaked a few. I'm realizing there is a bunch of small things that are still a bit unclear

I'm a little confused on the interrupts. For me at least I want to interrupt on both edges.

```
error = request_threaded_irq(irq, NULL, pwr_button_irq_handler,
             IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING | IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING,
             "powerbtn", NULL);
```

Seems Ok? Is threaded really necessary?
irq: I converted the gpio I want to monitor to an irq (gpio_to_irq()), will I still be able to read the gpio afterwards? If not can I make two different handlers for each edge?

handler: maybe I should put my handler here? I imagine its not threaded at this point

thread_fn: creates a thread to run my handler.. seems simple

irqflags: I put both edges in for now

devname: I can put anything in here I want? I imagine its something that can be seen with debugfs?

dev_id: umm from the documentation "A cookie passed back to the handler function"... wtf does that even mean? My book says its a pointer used for shared interrupts. So does that mean I'm getting a unique id from this? But some other drivers I'm looking at are passing data into it, is this an output or an input?

All I need to support is sleep, wake, and power off with this button... is this the right way to do this?

update:
I've discovered you can share IRQ with GPIO reads on the same pin. Although occasionally it seems that it misses one of the edges when the button gets released.

dev_id is an input but since i didn't have a device structure for gpio i used an address to my irq value instead. Should I have used a structure for a gpio input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the request_irq() API. From around 2.6.30, it's a wrapper around request_threaded_irq():

```
static inline int __must_check 
request_irq(unsigned int irq, irq_handler_t handler, unsigned long flags, 
        const char *name, void *dev) 
{ 
    return request_threaded_irq(irq, handler, NULL, flags, name, dev); 
}
```

Why threaded interrupts?? Well, it's work by Thomas Gleixner and others for the Linux (hard) RT patch (called PREEMPT_RT; it's an invasive patch that literally converts Linux into an RTOS!). In a nutshell, it's there in order to support prioritized interrupt handlers and to have the ability to have interrupt code-paths preemptible by 'real-time' usermode threads! [Pl see this link for more detail.](http://lwn.net/Articles/302043/) [And this one (slides).](http://elinux.org/images/e/ef/InterruptThreads-Slides_Anderson.pdf%E2%80%8E)

Note though, that driver developers still have a choice: use request_irq() with the IRQF_NO_THREAD (“Interrupt cannot be threaded”) to use the "traditional / old / classic" approach. (Most driver's don't do this).

Coming to the params:
'handler' is the interrupt handler of course, which will be threaded by default.
'flags' is as you said..
'name' is any name you want to give it (driver name); it shows up in the o/p of /proc/interrupts
'dev' is a "cookie" :-) Yeah, it's just a unique value you pass along, typically, a pointer to your 'driver context' data structure which is a hold-all for all imp info you'd like available.

Also, btw, the threaded interrupt model does away with the need for a separate "bottom-half" handler. (They still exist, it's just that we don't need to explicitly set them up).

Comment: Excellent thanks,

So whats the general rule if you don't have a device, or is there a device struct for a gpio?

I found the issue with missing the edges, the bug is I have two falling edges in the argument list, but the value is still changing so depending on how fast it runs through the code... it might catch it on an edge.

Comment: Is there a good example anywhere for setting a gpio as a wake source?

Comment: enable_irq_wake()
You still have to set it to an irq though